# How to find stackpointer for buffer overflow bug?

Tags: linux, security, assembly, buffer-overflow

I've read that stack usually starts in same address so the attacker may guess the starting point of the buffer to overflow. This is necessary to know this address to make the malicious code run. I made a program with a few lines of code to get the stack pointer address each time it starts and print it on the screen:

```
int * get_stack_pointer(){
   __asm__("mov %esp,%eax");
}
void main(){
  printf("Address: %p\n",get_stack_pointer());
}
```

And this is disassembly of the program:

```
<get_stack_pointer>:
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
mov    %esp,%eax
pop    %rbp
retq   

<main>:
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
mov    $0x0,%eax
callq  40050c <get_stack_pointer>
mov    %rax,%rsi
mov    $0x4005ec,%edi
mov    $0x0,%eax
callq  4003e0 <printf@plt>
pop    %rbp
retq
```

But each time I start the program I get different addresses. Some of theme are as following:

Address: 0xc31b2c80
Address: 0x2e041e0
Address: 0x7b003190
Address: 0xb3fd1350

So in this case how it possible for the attacker to run his code on the vulnerable program? (my OS is Linux 64bit)

EDIT: I made another program in assembly which includes a few simple lines. I just check the value of RSP every time it starts with debugger and I see always RSP has the same value but not the program written in c.

Comment: Because where the stack starts does change. Partly because environment variables are loaded before the stack, and their length changes, but mostly because modern OSs use something called Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) to confound exactly the types of attacks you're attempting. However, assuming there are no canaries on the stack, you can get around this by overwriting the return address. Addresses in .text don't change. I forget how to get around x64 register calling convention... Although it depends on the program, really. Oh! And variadic functions use stack args.

Comment: That's ASLR. Attackers must use other tricks to get the stack pointer if they need it. For educational purposes, you can turn ASLR off.

Comment: Same thing doesn't happen with a similar program wrote in assembly, I made another program and put a breakpoint in it and checked value of rsp. Every time the program starts, RSP has the same value.
Besides, many successful buffer-overflow attacks are performed on modern OSs you're talking about. how are they done?

Comment: @user2808671 ["How are they done?"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-to-libc_attack) Although... Yeah, different for 64 bit. I'll need to look into that.

Comment: @ParthianShot but  why the stack pointer is the same in the other program I coded in assembly?

Comment: @user2808671 Honestly? I'm not sure. What does running `cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` report?

Comment: @ParthianShot the output is 2

Comment: @user2808671 Hm. Not sure. What I will do is upvote the question so that someone who does know will find it.